# Проблемы в работе с Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка, google-maps-api

Здравствуйте! Нахожусь в несколько затруднительной ситуации: имеется несколько карт: на [главной](http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/main-page.html) и [другой](http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/city-page.html) странице. Проблема в том, что мне удается подключить только одну карту.

Не менее огорчает и то, что при переносе [рабочей карты в codepen](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/qaerRP), в консоли появляется непонятная мне ошибка и карта не отображается.

Застрял на этом вопросе основательно, очень прошу помочь разобраться с тем, почему карта в кодпене не работает и как там же подключить еще одну карту..

Ниже - код подключения карты, [полный пример на кодпен](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/qaerRP)..

```
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.893998, 33.611301);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatlng,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    styles: stylesArray
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

var image = 'img/marker-map.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    icon: image
});

var theElement = document.getElementById("address_content");
var contentString = theElement.innerHTML;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Comment: На сколько я знаю в Google Maps API нужен KEY для доступу к api. Возможно дело в этом?

Comment: Все верно, key нужен, он есть и подключен

Comment: А функция initialize одна и та же для нескольких карт на странице? Примеры на  codepen недоступны, потому и спрашиваю