# Календарь. Изменение кол-ва отображающихся месяцев в зависимости от разрешения

Tags: javascript, css, адаптивная-верстка

Есть весьма удобный [плагин календаря](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp#localization). Один из немногочисленных недостатков этого плагина в том, что в нем, судя по всему, не предусмотрена возможность изменения количества отображающихся месяцев в зависимости от ширины экрана (по крайней мере я её не вижу). [Ссылка](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/yVBYpG?editors=1010) на календарь в кодпене.

Есть идеи?

```js
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  pickmeup('.three-calendars', {
    flat: true,
    mode: 'range',
    calendars: 3
  });
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/css/pickmeup.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/js/pickmeup.js"></script>

<div class="three-calendars"></div>
```

Comment: проверять ширину экрана и переинициировать календарь на нужное кол-во месяцев. судя по всему, через параметр "calendars: 3"

Comment: @lexxl, проблема в том, что мой уровень знаний js делает такую задачу едва ли выполнимой..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка ширины экрана и инициализация нужного количества месяцев через `calendars`

```js
function adaptCalendars() {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 380) {
    pickmeup('.three-calendars', {
      flat: true,
      mode: 'range',
      calendars: 1
    });
  } else if (window.innerWidth < 695) {
    pickmeup('.three-calendars', {
      flat: true,
      mode: 'range',
      calendars: 2
    });
  }
  else {
    pickmeup('.three-calendars', {
      flat: true,
      mode: 'range',
      calendars: 3
    });
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", adaptCalendars);
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/css/pickmeup.css">
<script src="http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/js/pickmeup.js"></script>
<div class="three-calendars"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Взгляните пожалуйста и сюда, если будет время и желание, буду очень благодарен: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585286/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-google-maps-api

Comment: можно ли отслеживать ширину экрана не только при загрузке, а и при его ресайзе?

Comment: можно. для этого существует событие resize - аналогично событию load

Comment: добавил в ваш скрипт строку `window.onresize = adaptCalendars;` - по логике вещей все должно работать, но нет - кол-во месяцев не меняется. http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/yVBYpG?editors=1010

Comment: @Игорь да, мне тоже не удалось достучаться до смены при ресайзе. вероятно надо ждать, пока автор плагина добавит встроенный метод пересчета.

Answer (score 1):

Просто укажите условие (или несколько условий) проверки ширины экрана, по которому будет подставляться нужное кол-во календарей:

```
var numberСalendars = 3; // по умолчанию
if(window.innerWidth < 768){ // нужное разрешение экрана
    numberСalendars = 2; // или 1
}
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    pickmeup('.three-calendars', {
        flat: true,
        mode: 'range',
        calendars: numberСalendars
    });
});
```